# Cygwin function "settitle"

Tags: bash, cygwin

I was checking the `.bashrc` file that is installed by Cygwin and I found with a commented function named `settitle`:

```
settitle ()
{
   echo -ne "\e]2;$@\a\e]1;$@\a";
}
```

I would like to know what exactly does this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It changes the title of your window by outputting a special string, called an escape sequence. Read (a lot) more about ANSI escape sequences [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), on the [Bash Prompt HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/c327.html) and at the [ANSI escape sequence reference](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php).

Answer (score 1):

It sets the title of your terminal emulator window to its arguments.